# Nginx centos7 forbidden

Tags: nginx, centos, centos7

I Install nginx, but i have this error in my log file

```
[error] 2658#2658: *2 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is 
forbidden, client: 192.168.1.2, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.6"
```

My file config is this :

```
user  nginx;

worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    server{
        listen 80;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php index.html;
        server_name 192.168.1.10;
        location ~ \.php$ {
#root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
#       include fastcgi_params;
#       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
#      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
#        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:80;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
 include        fastcgi_params;
        }
         location ~ /\.ht {
                         deny all;
         }
    }

}

`
```

But i have 403 forbidden.
I tried to:

- Chmod -R 775 /usr/src
- Chmod o+x /usr
- Chown -R nginx:nginx /usr/share

i don't know what i do :(

Thanks you for the Help, 
Have a Nice Days.

Davide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it.
it's my new nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include   /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    server{
            listen 80;
            root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            server_name 192.168.1.6;
            location ~ \.php$ {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;

fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                }
                 location ~ /\.ht {
                                     deny all;
                 }
        }

}
```